# Copy row and paste below when cell value found in a column

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, copy-paste

I have pretty limited knowledge of VBA so hopefully I can explain what I'm trying to do! I'm trying to copy a row if it has anything > 0 in column J.

I then want to insert this copied row into a new row bellow that copied cell.

I would like this to loop through the whole worksheet so that every row with a value in J is repeated, the data in the worksheet varies in size, there will always be a value in column B till the data ends...

Here's my failed attempt to far..

```
 Sub Copy_Cells()
    For Each Objcell In ActiveSheet.Columns(10).Cells
    Do
     If Objcell.Value > 0 Then
         Objcell.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
         Exit Sub
         Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Cells)
    End If
Next Objcell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
Sub Copy_Cells()
    botRow = 100
    For i = botRow To 1 Step -1
      If Cells(i, 10).Value > 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

You would need to set the bottom row or you can implement a count of the used rows etc.

Comment: @hb332 [You should Accept the answer if it help you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copy_Cells()
   Dim totalRow as Integer
   totalRow = Activesheet.Cells(1,2).End(xlDown).Row 'Count total row from B column
   For Each Objcell In Activesheet.Range("J1:J" & totalRow)
       If Objcell.Value > 0 Then
            Objcell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
       End If
   Next Objcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this seemed to continue to copy and paste the rows with values in J. I've used both comments and ended up with this, works great.
   Sub Copy_Cells()
    botRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    For i = botRow To 1 Step -1
      If Cells(i, 10).Value > 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
      Next i
   End Sub
Thanks both!